# Array to string conversion problem in php

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

```php
foreach($data['sku'] as $key=>$val) {
    $attribute = new ProductsAttributes;
    $attribute->product_id = $id;
    $attribute->sku = $val;
    $attribute->size = $data['size'][$key];
    $attribute->price = $data['price'][$key];
    $attribute->stock = $data['stock'][$key];
    $attribute->save();
}
```

I don't understand this code because of `$data['size'][$key]`.
Why do I have to use `$key` instead of `$val` ?
If I use `$val`, it throws an `array to string conversion error`

Comment: You need to show what the values of $data['sku'] is, try with dd($data['sku']);

Answer (score 2):

You have to use like this

```
foreach($data as $key=>$val) {
    $attribute = new ProductsAttributes;
    $attribute->product_id = $id;
    $attribute->sku = $val['sku'];
    $attribute->size = $val['size'];
    $attribute->price = $val['price'];
    $attribute->stock = $val['stock'];
    $attribute->save();
}
```